# Choose a Character - Swift/SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game where the player gets to choose the character they want to play with. Currently I have a scene where they choose the character, and when they click on one it transitions to the scene where they play the game. I tried to do this by setting an integer value based on the character they choose and then using NSUserDefaults to have this integer value available in the next scene where I made conditionals that determined the texture of the character (based on who they chose). But it didnt work, and my character is showing up without a texture.

MY QUESTION IS what's a better way of doing this?

This is what I have currently for:

I have two functions that create the two characters in the game scene, and I call them like this depending on the character chosen in the scene where the player chooses a character:

```
  if choosePlayer == 1{

        addDrake()
    }else if choosePlayer == 2{

        addFuture()
    }
```

Currently there is no character showing up at all.

UPDATE:

I printed the choosePlayer variable and I found the problem - it is staying equal to 0 for some reason. In my choose character scene, when a player chooses one of the characters, its supposed to change the value of choosePlayer (which is initially set to Int()) and then transitions to the next scene. SO lets say they click on Future. This is my code for that:

```
else if chooseFuture.containsPoint(location){

        choosePlayer = 2

        let playScene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
        let transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(0.0)
        playScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(playScene, transition: transition)
    }
```

Comment: Did you remember to sync the NSUserDefaults when passing it in?  If you don't call the sync, it will just buffer until there is enough data.

Comment: Yes I did. I think the error isnt in the NSUserdefaults. I think its in setting up the texture. How should i go about doing that? I have one player node, and the texture depends on which character they choose in the first scene.

Comment: I don't know.  You will need to provide more information in your question.  What do you have currently?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `addDrake()` or `addFuture()` directly instead of worrying about the NSUserDefaults?  Are you sure that the scene is presented?  Would it be possible to see those methods?  Are you sure they are added to the scene?  Are they in a position that is off of the viewing area?  Sorry if those questions are a little obvious, but you never know.

Comment: I edited my question again because I found the problem but still dont know what to do about it. Please look at the UPDATE section

Comment: Learn to use enumerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you have your `print`, but you need to call your NSUserDefault setting *before* presenting the `playScene`.  In fact, as you have a reference to the `playScene`, just move your `choosePlayer` variable to the `playScene`, and don't even use the NSUserDefaults.

So in your PlayScene.swift have a variable called `choosePlayer`.  And in the UPDATE area's code, run `playScene.choosePlayer = 2` (after the `let playScene = PlayScene(size: self.size)`) instead of `choosePlayer = 2`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS WORKED PERFECTLY!!!! Sorry I just started making indie-style apps and I'm very inexperienced, so thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: @PineAppleJuiceApps  No problem!  Glad to help.